# How to update the PNR Capcha added in the Indian Railways Site

Tags: java, android, json, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a PNR Inquiry app on Google Play. It was working very fine. But recently Indian Railwys added captcha to their PNR Inquiry section and because of this I am not able to pass proper data to the server to get proper response. How to add this captcha in my app in form of an imageview and ask the users to enter captcha details also so that I can send proper data and get proper response.

[Indian Railways PNR Inquiry Link](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html)

Here is my PnrCheck.java which I was using earlier. Please help what modifications should be done here..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.ExecutionContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestExpectContinue;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestTargetHost;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestUserAgent;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class PNRStatusCheck {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String pnr1 = "1154177041";
            String reqStr = "lccp_pnrno1=" + pnr1 + "&submitpnr=Get+Status";
            PNRStatusCheck check = new PNRStatusCheck();
            StringBuffer data = check.getPNRResponse(reqStr, "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnrstat_cgi.cgi");
            if(data != null) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                PNRStatus pnr = check.parseHtml(data);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public StringBuffer getPNRResponse(String reqStr, String urlAddr) throws Exception {
        String urlHost = null;
        int port;
        String method = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlAddr);
            urlHost = url.getHost();
            port = url.getPort();
            method = url.getFile();

            // validate port
            if(port == -1) {
                port = url.getDefaultPort();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "HttpComponents/1.1");
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

        BasicHttpProcessor httpproc = new BasicHttpProcessor();
        // Required protocol interceptors
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestContent());
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestTargetHost());
        // Recommended protocol interceptors
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestConnControl());
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestUserAgent());
        httpproc.addInterceptor(new RequestExpectContinue());

        HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();
        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
        HttpHost host = new HttpHost(urlHost, port);
        DefaultHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultHttpClientConnection();

        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_CONNECTION, conn);
        context.setAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST, host);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String resData = null;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String statusStr = null;
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            String REQ_METHOD = method;
            String[] targets = { REQ_METHOD };

            for (int i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
                if (!conn.isOpen()) {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
                    conn.bind(socket, params);
                }
                BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest req = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("POST", targets[i]);
                req.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(new ByteArrayInputStream(reqStr.toString().getBytes()), reqStr.length()));
                req.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                req.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7");
                req.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
                req.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
                req.setHeader("Origin", "http://www.indianrail.gov.in");
                req.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
                req.setHeader("Referer", "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html");
                //req.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
                req.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                req.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");


                httpexecutor.preProcess(req, httpproc, context);

                HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(req, conn, context);
                response.setParams(params);
                httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, context);

                Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
                for(int j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
                    if(headers[j].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ERROR_MSG")) {
                        resData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    } 
                }
                statusStr = response.getStatusLine().toString();
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                if(in != null) {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                }

                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buff.append(line + "\n");
                }
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return buff;
    }

    public PNRStatus parseHtml(StringBuffer data) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        if(data != null) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.toString().getBytes())));
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        String line = null;
        TrainDetails trainDetails = new TrainDetails();
        List<PassengerDetails> passDetailsList = new ArrayList<PassengerDetails>();
        PassengerDetails passDetails = null;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.startsWith("<TD") && line.contains("table_border_both")) {
                line = line.replace("<B>", "");
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf("\">")+2, line.indexOf("</")).trim();

                if(line.contains("CHART")) {
                    trainDetails.setChatStatus(line);
                    break;
                }
                if(i > 7) {//Passenger Details
                    if(passDetails == null) {
                        passDetails = new PassengerDetails();
                    }
                    switch(i) {
                    case 8 :
                        passDetails.setName(line);
                        break;
                    case 9 :
                        passDetails.setBookingStatus(line.replace(" ", ""));
                        break;
                    case 10 :
                        passDetails.setCurrentStatus(line.replace(" ", ""));
                        i = 7;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(i == 7 ) {
                        passDetailsList.add(passDetails);
                        passDetails = null;
                    }

                } else { // Train details
                    switch(i){
                    case 0 :
                            trainDetails.setNumber(line);
                            break;
                    case 1 :
                            trainDetails.setName(line);
                            break;
                    case 2 :
                            trainDetails.setBoardingDate(line);
                            break;
                    case 3 :
                            trainDetails.setFrom(line);
                            break;
                    case 4 :
                            trainDetails.setTo(line);
                            break;
                    case 5 :
                            trainDetails.setReservedUpto(line);
                            break;
                    case 6 :
                            trainDetails.setBoardingPoint(line);
                            break;
                    case 7 :
                            trainDetails.setReservedType(line);
                            break;
                    default :
                        break;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        if(trainDetails.getNumber() != null) {
            PNRStatus pnrStatus = new PNRStatus();
            pnrStatus.setTrainDetails(trainDetails);
            pnrStatus.setPassengerDetails(passDetailsList);
            return pnrStatus;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Has anyone tried to see this question.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer on one post asking same:

If you check the html code, its actualy pretty bad captcha. Background of captcha is: http://www.indianrail.gov.in/1.jpg Those numbers are actualy in input tag:

What they are doing is, via javascript, use numbers from that hidden input tag and put them on that span with "captcha" background.

So basicaly your flow is:

read their html

get "captcha" (lol, funny captcha though) value from input field

when user puts data in your PNR field and presses Get Status

post form field, put PNR in proper value, put captcha in proper value

parse response

Oh yeah, one more thing. You can put any value in hidden input and "captcha" input, as long as they are the same. They aren't checking it via session or anything.

EDIT (code sample for submiting form): To simplify posting form i recommend HttpClient components from Apache: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi Lets say you downloaded HttpClient 4.3.1. Include client, core and mime libraries in your project (copy to libs folder, right click on project, properties, Java Build Path, Libraries, Add Jars -> add those 3.).

Code example would be:

```
private static final String FORM_TARGET = "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnstat_cgi.cgi";
private static final String INPUT_PNR = "lccp_pnrno1";
private static final String INPUT_CAPTCHA = "lccp_capinp_val";
private static final String INPUT_CAPTCHA_HIDDEN = "lccp_cap_val";

private void getHtml(String userPnr) {
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addTextBody(INPUT_PNR, userPnr); // users PNR code
    builder.addTextBody(INPUT_CAPTCHA, "123456");
    builder.addTextBody("submit", "Get Status");
    builder.addTextBody(INPUT_CAPTCHA_HIDDEN, "123456"); // values don't
                                                            // matter as
                                                            // long as they
                                                            // are the same

    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(FORM_TARGET);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse response = null;
    String htmlString = "";
    try {
        response = client.execute(httpPost);
        htmlString = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
                // now you can parse this string to get data you require.
    } catch (Exception letsIgnoreItForNow) {
    }
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ignoredOnceMore) {
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException manyIgnoredExceptions) {
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Also, be warned i didn't wrap this in `AsyncTask` call, so you will have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on that page and see the source on http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html, you'll find the source of function that generates the captcha, compare the captcha and validates it:

There is a javascript function hat draws the captcha:

```
//Generates the captcha function that draws the captcha  
function DrawCaptcha()
    {       
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';      
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ ''; 
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ ''; 
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ ''; 

    var code = a + b + c + d + e;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code; 
}

//Function to checking the form inputs:

function checkform(theform){
    var why = "";

    if(theform.txtInput.value == ""){
    why += "- Security code should not be empty.\n";
    }
    if(theform.txtInput.value != ""){
        if(ValidCaptcha(theform.txtInput.value) == false){ //here validating the captcha
            why += "- Security code did not match.\n";
        }
    }
    if(why != ""){
        alert(why);
        return false;
    }
}

// Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function  
function ValidCaptcha(){
    var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
    var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
    if (str1 == str2){
        return true;   
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

// Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
function removeSpaces(string){
    return string.split(' ').join('');
}
```

Also instead of using URL http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnrstat_cgi.cgi, try URL: http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnstat_cgi_28688.cgi . The previous one is down. I think it has been changed. 
Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to Android. Can you tell me what to do with these functions.? What to edit in the code I have provided.?

Comment: On a second thought, did you first try and use the new URL? Also as far as I can see, the captcha seems to be local. They are not sending it to server or anywhere. First try and update your URL's.

Comment: No.. The same thing is happening. it showing error processing Pnr. Can you please help how to add the captcha to the passing string.?

Comment: @Shobhit.. Are you there.?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I'll try to get back to it soon. I found those things instantaneously and thought might give you an starting point to proceed further. I can do the whole research for you but will try to help.

Comment: Did you find anything bro.?